# how to access other modules function in current module in symfony 1.0.6?

Tags: php, function, symfony1, module

I am using symfony 1.0.6 and I have directory structure as below:

> apps/frontend/module/news/action/action.class
>
> apps/jobseeker/module/profile/action/action.class

In news module of jobseeker application I have function named function `Docx2text() { }` and I want to use the same in profile module of jobseeker application.

How to do this without relocating functions to Utills or anyother static functions.

Comment: You can't. The only solution is to relocating functions to `lib` folder (on frontend level or on project level).

Comment: Uhh, you might want to consider updating. If not to 1.4, at least 1.0.22. Security updates and all that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are they on the same application or different? Because first you say they are in jobseekerand frontend and then both are in jobseeker?

I don't think is a good idea to use global functions on the models actions. Why can't you use a static or moving it to a Utils class?

Comment: news module is in front end application and profile module is in jobseeker application. Both frontend and jobseeker are in apps directory...
I want to use functions of modules of frontend IN modules of jobseeker